# flink sql client can't parse really simple sql?

Tags: flink-sql

**Environment**
flink version 1.15.1
kafka version  kafka_2.12-2.2.0

```
CREATE TABLE kafka_test (
  `event_time` TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'timestamp',
  `partition` BIGINT METADATA VIRTUAL,
  `offset` BIGINT METADATA VIRTUAL,
  `value` String
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'first',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'hxyh2:9092',
  'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
  'format' = 'raw'
);
```

**result:**

1. When I execute 'select * from kafka_test' ,it work well show result realtime.
2. When I execute "select * from kafka_test where value like 'star'",it throw Exception which I don't what's that, I hope know what's possible problems cause this.

```
022-09-09 16:49:39,205 WARN  org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient                  [] - Could not execute SQL statement.
org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.SqlExecutionException: Failed to parse statement: select * from kafka_test where value like ‘start’;
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.parseStatement(LocalExecutor.java:174) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.SqlCommandParserImpl.parseCommand(SqlCommandParserImpl.java:45) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.SqlMultiLineParser.parse(SqlMultiLineParser.java:71) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.acceptLine(LineReaderImpl.java:2731) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.readLine(LineReaderImpl.java:585) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.getAndExecuteStatements(CliClient.java:296) [flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeInteractive(CliClient.java:281) [flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient.executeInInteractiveMode(CliClient.java:229) [flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.openCli(SqlClient.java:151) [flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.start(SqlClient.java:95) [flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.startClient(SqlClient.java:187) [flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.SqlClient.main(SqlClient.java:161) [flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.SqlParserException: SQL parse failed. Encountered "value" at line 1, column 32.
Was expecting one of:
    "CURSOR" ...
    "EXISTS" ...
    "NOT" ...
    "ROW" ...
    "(" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "INTERVAL" ...
    <UNSIGNED_INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <DECIMAL_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
    <APPROX_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
    <BINARY_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <PREFIXED_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <QUOTED_STRING> ...
    <UNICODE_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <BIG_QUERY_DOUBLE_QUOTED_STRING> ...
    <BIG_QUERY_QUOTED_STRING> ...
    "TRUE" ...
    "FALSE" ...
    "UNKNOWN" ...
    "NULL" ...
    <LBRACE_D> ...
    <LBRACE_T> ...
    <LBRACE_TS> ...
    "DATE" ...
    "TIME" ...
    "TIMESTAMP" ...
    "?" ...
    "CAST" ...
    "EXTRACT" ...
    "POSITION" ...
    "CONVERT" ...
    "TRANSLATE" ...
    "OVERLAY" ...
    "FLOOR" ...
    "CEIL" ...
    "CEILING" ...
    "SUBSTRING" ...
    "TRIM" ...
    "CLASSIFIER" ...
    "MATCH_NUMBER" ...
    "RUNNING" ...
    "PREV" ...
    "NEXT" ...
    "JSON_EXISTS" ...
    "JSON_VALUE" ...
    "JSON_QUERY" ...
    "JSON_OBJECT" ...
    "JSON_OBJECTAGG" ...
    "JSON_ARRAY" ...
    "JSON_ARRAYAGG" ...
    <LBRACE_FN> ...
    "MULTISET" ...
    "ARRAY" ...
    "PERIOD" ...
    "SPECIFIC" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <HYPHENATED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    "ABS" ...
    "AVG" ...
    "CARDINALITY" ...
    "CHAR_LENGTH" ...
    "CHARACTER_LENGTH" ...
    "COALESCE" ...
    "COLLECT" ...
    "COVAR_POP" ...
    "COVAR_SAMP" ...
    "CUME_DIST" ...
    "COUNT" ...
    "CURRENT_DATE" ...
    "CURRENT_TIME" ...
    "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" ...
    "DENSE_RANK" ...
    "ELEMENT" ...
    "EVERY" ...
    "EXP" ...
    "FIRST_VALUE" ...
    "FUSION" ...
    "INTERSECTION" ...
    "GROUPING" ...
    "HOUR" ...
    "LAG" ...
    "LEAD" ...
    "LEFT" ...
    "LAST_VALUE" ...
    "LN" ...
    "LOCALTIME" ...
    "LOCALTIMESTAMP" ...
    "LOWER" ...
    "MAX" ...
    "MIN" ...
    "MINUTE" ...
    "MOD" ...
    "MONTH" ...
    "NTH_VALUE" ...
    "NTILE" ...
    "NULLIF" ...
    "OCTET_LENGTH" ...
    "PERCENT_RANK" ...
    "POWER" ...
    "RANK" ...
    "REGR_COUNT" ...
    "REGR_SXX" ...
    "REGR_SYY" ...
    "RIGHT" ...
    "ROW_NUMBER" ...
    "SECOND" ...
    "SOME" ...
    "SQRT" ...
    "STDDEV_POP" ...
    "STDDEV_SAMP" ...
    "SUM" ...
    "UPPER" ...
    "TRUNCATE" ...
    "USER" ...
    "VAR_POP" ...
    "VAR_SAMP" ...
    "YEAR" ...
    "CURRENT_CATALOG" ...
    "CURRENT_DEFAULT_TRANSFORM_GROUP" ...
    "CURRENT_PATH" ...
    "CURRENT_ROLE" ...
    "CURRENT_SCHEMA" ...
    "CURRENT_USER" ...
    "SESSION_USER" ...
    "SYSTEM_USER" ...
    "NEW" ...
    "CASE" ...
    "CURRENT" ...
    
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.parse.CalciteParser.parseSqlList(CalciteParser.java:82) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.ParserImpl.parse(ParserImpl.java:101) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.lambda$parseStatement$1(LocalExecutor.java:172) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.ExecutionContext.wrapClassLoader(ExecutionContext.java:88) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.parseStatement(LocalExecutor.java:172) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException: Encountered "value" at line 1, column 32.
Was expecting one of:
    "CURSOR" ...
    "EXISTS" ...
    "NOT" ...
    "ROW" ...
    "(" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "INTERVAL" ...
    <UNSIGNED_INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <DECIMAL_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
    <APPROX_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
    <BINARY_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <PREFIXED_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <QUOTED_STRING> ...
    <UNICODE_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <BIG_QUERY_DOUBLE_QUOTED_STRING> ...
    <BIG_QUERY_QUOTED_STRING> ...
    "TRUE" ...
    "FALSE" ...
    "UNKNOWN" ...
    "NULL" ...
    <LBRACE_D> ...
    <LBRACE_T> ...
    <LBRACE_TS> ...
    "DATE" ...
    "TIME" ...
    "TIMESTAMP" ...
    "?" ...
    "CAST" ...
    "EXTRACT" ...
    "POSITION" ...
    "CONVERT" ...
    "TRANSLATE" ...
    "OVERLAY" ...
    "FLOOR" ...
    "CEIL" ...
    "CEILING" ...
    "SUBSTRING" ...
    "TRIM" ...
    "CLASSIFIER" ...
    "MATCH_NUMBER" ...
    "RUNNING" ...
    "PREV" ...
    "NEXT" ...
    "JSON_EXISTS" ...
    "JSON_VALUE" ...
    "JSON_QUERY" ...
    "JSON_OBJECT" ...
    "JSON_OBJECTAGG" ...
    "JSON_ARRAY" ...
    "JSON_ARRAYAGG" ...
    <LBRACE_FN> ...
    "MULTISET" ...
    "ARRAY" ...
    "PERIOD" ...
    "SPECIFIC" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <HYPHENATED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    "ABS" ...
    "AVG" ...
    "CARDINALITY" ...
    "CHAR_LENGTH" ...
    "CHARACTER_LENGTH" ...
    "COALESCE" ...
    "COLLECT" ...
    "COVAR_POP" ...
    "COVAR_SAMP" ...
    "CUME_DIST" ...
    "COUNT" ...
    "CURRENT_DATE" ...
    "CURRENT_TIME" ...
    "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" ...
    "DENSE_RANK" ...
    "ELEMENT" ...
    "EVERY" ...
    "EXP" ...
    "FIRST_VALUE" ...
    "FUSION" ...
    "INTERSECTION" ...
    "GROUPING" ...
    "HOUR" ...
    "LAG" ...
    "LEAD" ...
    "LEFT" ...
    "LAST_VALUE" ...
    "LN" ...
    "LOCALTIME" ...
    "LOCALTIMESTAMP" ...
    "LOWER" ...
    "MAX" ...
    "MIN" ...
    "MINUTE" ...
    "MOD" ...
    "MONTH" ...
    "NTH_VALUE" ...
    "NTILE" ...
    "NULLIF" ...
    "OCTET_LENGTH" ...
    "PERCENT_RANK" ...
    "POWER" ...
    "RANK" ...
    "REGR_COUNT" ...
    "REGR_SXX" ...
    "REGR_SYY" ...
    "RIGHT" ...
    "ROW_NUMBER" ...
    "SECOND" ...
    "SOME" ...
    "SQRT" ...
    "STDDEV_POP" ...
    "STDDEV_SAMP" ...
    "SUM" ...
    "UPPER" ...
    "TRUNCATE" ...
    "USER" ...
    "VAR_POP" ...
    "VAR_SAMP" ...
    "YEAR" ...
    "CURRENT_CATALOG" ...
    "CURRENT_DEFAULT_TRANSFORM_GROUP" ...
    "CURRENT_PATH" ...
    "CURRENT_ROLE" ...
    "CURRENT_SCHEMA" ...
    "CURRENT_USER" ...
    "SESSION_USER" ...
    "SYSTEM_USER" ...
    "NEW" ...
    "CASE" ...
    "CURRENT" ...
    
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.convertException(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:472) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.normalizeException(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:235) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.handleException(SqlParser.java:140) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseStmtList(SqlParser.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.parse.CalciteParser.parseSqlList(CalciteParser.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.ParserImpl.parse(ParserImpl.java:101) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.lambda$parseStatement$1(LocalExecutor.java:172) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.ExecutionContext.wrapClassLoader(ExecutionContext.java:88) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.parseStatement(LocalExecutor.java:172) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered "value" at line 1, column 32.
Was expecting one of:
    "CURSOR" ...
    "EXISTS" ...
    "NOT" ...
    "ROW" ...
    "(" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "INTERVAL" ...
    <UNSIGNED_INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <DECIMAL_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
    <APPROX_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
    <BINARY_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <PREFIXED_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <QUOTED_STRING> ...
    <UNICODE_STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <BIG_QUERY_DOUBLE_QUOTED_STRING> ...
    <BIG_QUERY_QUOTED_STRING> ...
    "TRUE" ...
    "FALSE" ...
    "UNKNOWN" ...
    "NULL" ...
    <LBRACE_D> ...
    <LBRACE_T> ...
    <LBRACE_TS> ...
    "DATE" ...
    "TIME" ...
    "TIMESTAMP" ...
    "?" ...
    "CAST" ...
    "EXTRACT" ...
    "POSITION" ...
    "CONVERT" ...
    "TRANSLATE" ...
    "OVERLAY" ...
    "FLOOR" ...
    "CEIL" ...
    "CEILING" ...
    "SUBSTRING" ...
    "TRIM" ...
    "CLASSIFIER" ...
    "MATCH_NUMBER" ...
    "RUNNING" ...
    "PREV" ...
    "NEXT" ...
    "JSON_EXISTS" ...
    "JSON_VALUE" ...
    "JSON_QUERY" ...
    "JSON_OBJECT" ...
    "JSON_OBJECTAGG" ...
    "JSON_ARRAY" ...
    "JSON_ARRAYAGG" ...
    <LBRACE_FN> ...
    "MULTISET" ...
    "ARRAY" ...
    "PERIOD" ...
    "SPECIFIC" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <HYPHENATED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    "ABS" ...
    "AVG" ...
    "CARDINALITY" ...
    "CHAR_LENGTH" ...
    "CHARACTER_LENGTH" ...
    "COALESCE" ...
    "COLLECT" ...
    "COVAR_POP" ...
    "COVAR_SAMP" ...
    "CUME_DIST" ...
    "COUNT" ...
    "CURRENT_DATE" ...
    "CURRENT_TIME" ...
    "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" ...
    "DENSE_RANK" ...
    "ELEMENT" ...
    "EVERY" ...
    "EXP" ...
    "FIRST_VALUE" ...
    "FUSION" ...
    "INTERSECTION" ...
    "GROUPING" ...
    "HOUR" ...
    "LAG" ...
    "LEAD" ...
    "LEFT" ...
    "LAST_VALUE" ...
    "LN" ...
    "LOCALTIME" ...
    "LOCALTIMESTAMP" ...
    "LOWER" ...
    "MAX" ...
    "MIN" ...
    "MINUTE" ...
    "MOD" ...
    "MONTH" ...
    "NTH_VALUE" ...
    "NTILE" ...
    "NULLIF" ...
    "OCTET_LENGTH" ...
    "PERCENT_RANK" ...
    "POWER" ...
    "RANK" ...
    "REGR_COUNT" ...
    "REGR_SXX" ...
    "REGR_SYY" ...
    "RIGHT" ...
    "ROW_NUMBER" ...
    "SECOND" ...
    "SOME" ...
    "SQRT" ...
    "STDDEV_POP" ...
    "STDDEV_SAMP" ...
    "SUM" ...
    "UPPER" ...
    "TRUNCATE" ...
    "USER" ...
    "VAR_POP" ...
    "VAR_SAMP" ...
    "YEAR" ...
    "CURRENT_CATALOG" ...
    "CURRENT_DEFAULT_TRANSFORM_GROUP" ...
    "CURRENT_PATH" ...
    "CURRENT_ROLE" ...
    "CURRENT_SCHEMA" ...
    "CURRENT_USER" ...
    "SESSION_USER" ...
    "SYSTEM_USER" ...
    "NEW" ...
    "CASE" ...
    "CURRENT" ...
    
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.generateParseException(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:42459) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.jj_consume_token(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:42270) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.Expression3(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:21231) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.Expression2b(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:20828) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.Expression2(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:20869) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.Expression(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:20800) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.WhereOpt(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:15587) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.SqlSelect(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:9013) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.LeafQuery(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:714) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.LeafQueryOrExpr(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:20783) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.QueryOrExpr(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:20226) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.OrderedQueryOrExpr(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:588) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.SqlStmt(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:3980) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.SqlStmtList(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:2911) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.parseSqlStmtList(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:287) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseStmtList(SqlParser.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.parse.CalciteParser.parseSqlList(CalciteParser.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.ParserImpl.parse(ParserImpl.java:101) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.lambda$parseStatement$1(LocalExecutor.java:172) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.context.ExecutionContext.wrapClassLoader(ExecutionContext.java:88) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor.parseStatement(LocalExecutor.java:172) ~[flink-sql-client-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    ... 11 more
```

thanks

I tried to find any detail to solve it and execute smoothly but failed.
Great thanks for anyone can give suggestion.

Comment: Fixed  select * from kafka_test where `value` like 'help';

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't used backticks to escape the word "values". Since `values` is on the list of reserved keywords (see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/table/sql/overview/#reserved-keywords), this returns a grammar error